# High pitched webcam mic

Tags: 18.04

Recently upgraded my PC from Ubuntu 14.04LTS to 18.04LTS by doing a clean install, everything has gone fine with the exception of a pulseaudio issue with my Logitech C905 USB webcam. For some reason the mic sample rate is too high and I get Alvin & Chipmonks audio from it in a Hangouts video call. If I do a 'killall pulseaudio' from the terminal the daemon will automatically restart and then the mic rate is correct for a while but returns to high pitch on next use. How to correct?